# Sum of values in hourly range

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following table

| Date | Hour | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-17 | 15:21:00 | 1 |
| 2022-11-17 | 22:19:00 | 2 |
| 2022-11-18 | 00:44:00 | 2 |
| 2022-11-18 | 04:27:00 | 3 |
| 2022-11-18 | 13:21:00 | 2 |
| 2022-11-18 | 23:55:00 | 1 |
| 2022-11-19 | 09:01:00 | 4 |

Now I would like to sum the values based on the day and the specified hour range
It should sum from hour **6:00** of the previous day to hour **6:00** of today.

For example: So the first four rows should be the sum of 2022-11-17 and so on.

| Date (6-6) | Sum of values |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-11-17 | 8 |
| 2022-11-18 | 3 |
| 2022-11-19 | 4 |

At the moment I can sum values between hours, but on the same day

```
Usage = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Table[Value]), 
        TIME(
            HOUR(Table[Hour]), 
            MINUTE(Table[Hour]), 
            SECOND(Table[Hour])
        ) >= TIMEVALUE("02:00:00"), 
        TIME(
            HOUR(Table[Hour]), 
            MINUTE(Table[Hour]), 
            SECOND(Table[Hour])
        ) <= TIMEVALUE("14:00:00")
    )
```

`

Comment: I added a response based on your desired result - but note that this is contradictory to your explanation of `from hour 06:00 of the previous day to hour 06:00 of today`. Perhaps you meant `from hour 06:00 of current day to hour 06:00 of the next day`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this measure:

```
Usage = 
VAR _min_time = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Date] ) + TIME ( 6, 0, 0 )
VAR _max_time = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Date] ) + 1 + TIME ( 6, 0, 0 )
RETURN
IF ( 
    ISINSCOPE ( 'Table'[Date] ) ,
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ) ,
        FILTER ( 
            ALL ( 'Table' ) , 
            VAR _time = [Date] + [Hour] 
            RETURN _min_time < _time && _time <= _max_time 
        )
    )
)
```

Calculates your desired result:

[image]